# How can I pass a JSON object from Javascript to Java

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest

What I am trying to do is initiate an ajax call from my frontend code by user interaction. This calls a Java Restful service that I have written. And this Java function calls another service.

I need that java service in the middle because I need to send the inputs to other service in the format of "MyModel".

The problem is, the AJAX call works but it cannot get the JSON object that I send. You see in the Java function below I create the "param1" : "asdasd" for the second time there. That's because it cannot get the JSON data from front-end. It should be dynamically created with the argument of sendInputs function.

By the way when I debug the value String input is like this: ""

Javascript AJAX call:

```
var paramData = {"param1" : "asdasd"};

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : "/api/v2/proxy",
    dataType : "json",
    headers : {
        "Service-End-Point" : "http://localhost:9000/service/myService/sendInputs"
    },
    statusCode : {
        200 : function(data) {
        }
    },
    contentType : "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify(paramData),
    error : function(error) {

    }
});
```

Java consume:

```
@GET
@Path("/sendInputs")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sendInputs(String input) {
    String result = null;

    //define the service endpoint to be added the default URL
    String serviceEndpoint = "otherService/tool/runTool";

    List<MyModel> modelParameterList = new ArrayList<MyModel>();

    MyModel inputParameter = null;
    inputParameter = new MyModel("param1", "asdasd");
    modelParameterList.add(inputParameter);

    //convert the Java Map to a json string using Jackson ObjectMapper
    String jsonStringOfInputParameters = toJSON(modelParameterList);

    WebClient client = WebClient
            .create("http://localhost:9000");

    result = client.path(serviceEndpoint)
            .query("tool", "myTool")
            .query("input", jsonStringOfInputParameters)
            .accept("application/json")
            //tells cxf to convert the json to a string type upon return
            .get(String.class);

    // Return the json result as a string
    return result;
}
```

Comment: does /sendInputs get you json if you put in the browser?

Comment: then you issue in the server code not in the client code check your log file to find out what id the exception throws there, try to use try catch block in the catch print the exception trace and see why your server side code not work, then you can fix your js

Comment: Does your URLs correct? Is the controller called?

Comment: @shepard23 yes I am sure URL's are correct I tested them and they execute without inputs.

Comment: Is `MyModel` a class whose instances can be seralized to JSON? Do you use JAXB or some similar mapping technology?

Comment: does `input` in the `Java` function `sendInputs` represent the same `data` that you are passing in the `ajax` call?

Comment: @brainmassage: Did you got your problem solved?
I am struggling with the same issue? Can you help me with the solution by writing a comment

Answer (score 0):

your `paramData` variable is already a valid json. I do not think you need yo use `JSON.Stringify()` again.And what is this is the ajax call:

```
statusCode : {
        200 : function(data) {
        }
    }
```

Status code is supposed to be coming from the server in response.

Answer (score 0):

First, your ajax header should be like this:

```
headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
```

url:

```
url: "http://localhost:9000/service/myService/sendInputs"
```

Second, you need to have `MyModel` with `param1` field and Also setters and getters. And this can be your service method:

```
public String sendInputs(MyModel model)
{
      //model.getParam1() will be "asdasd"
}
```

Comment: I already have setters and getters. When I change headers I get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. When I open Chrome debugger I can see the JSON object in the Network tab. I think the fault is on the java part.